# Is it possible to reference .NET dll specifying multiple strong names

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-assembly

Can I specify somehow that a reference I'm adding has strong name X or strong name Y?

My .DLL references Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll. Unfortunately, its nuget version is too old and does not have some bugfixes. So I downloaded it from Github (it's newer there) and built it. So I'm now referencing my own version of Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll. This works but some users of my .DLL may need to use the original Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll (for instance, if they can install libs via nuget only) despite nuget's version does not have useful bugfixes.

I would like to have it that way so that my lib can reference any of Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll depending on which one will be around. So the reference must allow Strong name from Microsoft (which comes from nuget) and Strong name from me. Can I somehow specify the list of allowed strong names for the given .dll?

Comment: You can create facade for lib and in facade dynamic load different versions. Or if you don't need facade just dynamic load.

Comment: Thanks. However, I'm not sure if dynamic load is allowed in High Trust ASP.NET environments (at least by default). I heard serious limitations on Reflection are imposed on that level..

Comment: For instance, AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event which seemed to be suitable for my task is marked with SecurityCriticalAttribute and therefore "Requires full trust for the immediate caller. This member cannot be used by partially trusted or transparent code."

Answer (score 1):

> Can I specify somehow that a reference I'm adding has strong name X or strong name Y?

**No**, since you have not understood the concept well, please understand Strong name key not a mere nomenclature, this is form of encryption based on **public-private key combination**, where a binary is signed using **Private Key** and **Public Key** available with the user to ensure tamper proofing. You cannot do this since for `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll` you need Microsoft's certificate used for encryption, essentially access to their private key, which is not possible.

> You main issue, though you are Ok with compiling the code for `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll` from Github, but your customer may still get a Nuget version and they will not work together. Especially since its the same version, one signed, another unsigned

Your option is rename `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll` to a custom name, with custom namespace as you compile the binary, then though your code will use the Microsoft's code as a custom binary, customers can still get the Nuget version and their will not be any clash even in case they use the APIs directly or load it from GAC.

**Answering the OP's comments:**

**Comment1 :**

If you are exposing the types from the MS library, which means you will create a wrapper, then anyway the customer using your library and the Nuget library will have a tough time dealing with similar APIs, until and unless they are bundled under your unique namespace for clear demarcation. In fact please beware, even with signing this would not work because at a given point of time only one assembly with a given name and version can be loaded in the App Domain, signing  takes care of tamper proofing. Can work if you change the version too, but can lead to really strange and unexpected issues at run-time

**Comment2 :**

Thanks for further clarification, you want to just sign the MS library with your public-private key combination:

- As mentioned above will still not load, due to same name and version issue
- Option would be to rename or at least change the version

What you are trying to do will compile, but at run-time can lead to unexpected binary resolution issues. As you have the code from Github, preferable would be a mirror image with a custom name, to have 100% expected behavior.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not an option for me as the customers need to use the output from my lib and this output is Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll classes. I.e. my library not just uses this dll but exposes public API which utilizes types from it. Having two sets of types for the same will turn my customers life into nightmare. Seems the only option for me would be providing two versions of the .dll - one in nuget (compiled with nuget's version of MS dll) and another one - standalone (and compiled with Github version of MS dll)..

Comment: Also I'm not sure that you understood my question right. I wasn't trying to sign Exchange lib with MS certificate or ignore key checks. I wanted to reference Exchange library signed with MS or with my certificate. I.e. all source Exchange libs stay as-is while in my lib the reference would tell that Exchange lib must have Public Key "X" OR Public Key "Y". Just make it a vector of allowed public keys instead of scalar. Still, it would be a strict check because if the dll in question is not signed with X or Y, the reference would fail at runtime preventing unauthorized code from being executed.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, what I wanted was that people currently using MS version could easily switch to my version of Exchange lib (github's codebase) for a while and once MS updates nuget, they would effortlessly revert to MS version. With renaming namespaces it would not be that easy for them. So it seems I need to keep original namespaces. Yes, MS version and my version cannot co-exist in the same project but this is not needed, only one dll should be referenced at a time.

Comment: Update: I just found EWSCore project on nuget (just two weeks there) from MS and it seems this project has all the fixes needed, thus eliminating the need in my current question. I haven't found any info on this project in Google but it looks promising.

Comment: Looks like that EWSCore has nothing to do with MS.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40222095/where-can-find-any-info-on-ewscore-project