# Where can find any info on EWSCore project

Tags: .net, ews-managed-api

https://www.nuget.org/packages/EWSCore/

Google delivers nothing but this link (everything else is not relevant). Can I rely on this in my projects as Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll replacement? The lib seems to contain the same types as Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll (everything builds fine) and incorporates bugfixes from https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api but it lacks SHA digital signatures. And any docs..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it has no connection with Microsoft (despite "Copyright
© Microsoft Corporation." statement), public key token is different from 31bf3856ad364e35 which is used by MS.